# F# exception handling multiple "Tries"

Tags: exception, f#, try-catch

I'm trying to read a bunch of csv files in SQL Server using SQL Bulk Insert and DataContext.ExecuteCommand. (Maybe this isn't the best way to do it, but it does allow me stay in the Type Provider context--as opposed to with SqlBulkCopy I think.) Now the upload is glitchy with intermittent success. Some files read in, some fail with "Data conversion error (truncation)". I think this has to do with the row terminators not always working.

When the upload works, it seems to be with the '0x0A' terminator. But when that fails, I want to try repeatedly again with other row terminators. So I want to go into a Try statement, and on failure go into another Try statement, and another if that one fails, ... . This may not be the best way to upload, but I am still curious about the Try logic for it's own state.

Here's what I've come up with so far and it's not too pretty (but it works). Cutting out a few nested layers:

```
let FileRead path = 

    try
        db.DataContext.ExecuteCommand(@"BULK INSERT...ROWTERMINATOR='0x0A')") |> ignore 
        true
    with
        | exn -> 
            try
                db.DataContext.ExecuteCommand(@"BULK INSERT...ROWTERMINATOR='\r')") |> ignore 
                true
            with
                | exn -> 
                    try
                        db.DataContext.ExecuteCommand(@"BULK INSERT...ROWTERMINATOR='\n')") |> ignore 
                        true
                    with
                        | exn -> 
                            false
```

This doens't feel right but I haven't figured out any other syntax.

EDIT: What I ended up doing, just for the record. Appreciate being put on a productive path. There's plenty to improve in this. With one of the more significant things being to use Async's and run it Parallel (which I have gotten experience with in other sections).

```
type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<dbConnection>
let db = dbSchema.GetDataContext() 

let TryUpLd table pathFile rowTerm = 
    try
        db.DataContext.ExecuteCommand( @"BULK INSERT " + table + " FROM '" + pathFile + 
                                       @"' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR=',', FIRSTROW = 2, ROWTERMINATOR='" 
                                       + rowTerm + "')" ) |> ignore
        File.Delete (pathFile)  |> Some
    with
        | exn -> None

let NxtUpLd UL intOpt =
    match intOpt with
    | None -> UL
    | _ -> intOpt

let MoveTable ID table1 table2 = 
    //...
    ()

let NxtMoveTable MT intOpt = 
    match intOpt with
    | Some i -> MT
    | _ -> ()

let UpLdFile path (file:string) = 
    let (table1, table2) = 
        match path with
        | p when p = dlXPath   -> ("Data.dbo.ImportXs", "Data.dbo.Xs")
        | p when p = dlYPath -> ("Data.dbo.ImportYs", "Data.dbo.Ys")
        | _ -> ("ERROR path to tables", "")        

    let ID = file.Replace(fileExt, "")

    let TryRowTerm = TryUpLd table1 (path + file)

    TryRowTerm "0x0A" 
    |> NxtUpLd (TryRowTerm "\r")
    |> NxtUpLd (TryRowTerm "\n")
    |> NxtUpLd (TryRowTerm "\r\n")
    |> NxtUpLd (TryRowTerm "\n\r")
    |> NxtUpLd (TryRowTerm "\0")
    |> NxtMoveTable (MoveTable ID table1 table2) 


let UpLdData path = 
    let dir = new DirectoryInfo(path)
    let fileList = dir.GetFiles()

    fileList |> Array.iter (fun file -> UpLdFile path file.Name ) |> ignore
```

Comment: maybe just call in a loop?

Comment: That sounds good. Let me try a version that way. Thanks.

Comment: Though I would still also be curious if there might be a situation of wanting to try A then B then ..., until one succeeds--and the alternatives didn't lend them to a loop with simple substitution as in my case. How might one code that Try until not failure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, using monadic composition.

First, define a function that takes another function as input, but converts any exception to a `None` value:

```
let attempt f =
    try f () |> Some
    with | _ -> None
```

This function has the type `(unit -> 'a) -> 'a option`; that is: `f` is inferred to be any function that takes `unit` as input, and returns a value. As you can see, if no exception happens, the return value from invoking `f` is wrapped in a `Some` case. The `attempt` function suppresses all exceptions, which [you shouldn't normally do](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229007(v=vs.110).aspx).

Next, define this `attemptNext` function:

```
let attemptNext f = function
    | Some x -> Some x
    | None -> attempt f
```

This function has the type `(unit -> 'a) -> 'a option -> 'a option`. If the input `'a option` is `Some` then it's simply returned. In other words, the value is interpreted as already successful, so there's no reason to try the next function.

Otherwise, if the input `'a option` is `None`, this is interpreted as though the previous step resulted in a failure. In that case, the input function `f` is attempted, using the `attempt` function.

This means that you can now compose functions together, and get the first successful result.

Here are some functions to test with:

```
let throwyFunction () = raise (new System.InvalidOperationException("Boo"))
let throwyFunction' x y = raise (new System.InvalidOperationException("Hiss"))
let goodFunction () = "Hooray"
let goodFunction' x y = "Yeah"
```

Try them out in F# Interactive:

```
> let res1 =
    attempt throwyFunction
    |> attemptNext (fun () -> throwyFunction' 42 "foo")
    |> attemptNext goodFunction
    |> attemptNext (fun () -> goodFunction' true 13.37);;

val res1 : string option = Some "Hooray"

> let res2 =
    attempt goodFunction
    |> attemptNext throwyFunction
    |> attemptNext (fun () -> throwyFunction' 42 "foo")
    |> attemptNext (fun () -> goodFunction' true 13.37);;

val res2 : string option = Some "Hooray"

> let res3 =
    attempt (fun () -> throwyFunction' 42 "foo")
    |> attemptNext throwyFunction    
    |> attemptNext (fun () -> goodFunction' true 13.37)
    |> attemptNext goodFunction;;

val res3 : string option = Some "Yeah"

> let res4 =
    attempt (fun () -> throwyFunction' 42 "foo")
    |> attemptNext (fun () -> goodFunction' true 13.37)
    |> attemptNext throwyFunction    
    |> attemptNext goodFunction;;

val res4 : string option = Some "Yeah"
```

Comment: Thanks very much, Mark. This is great. So far I've only done reading on monads, so I'm very glad to finally try put some of the ideas in practice. Thanks again. I should wait a bit before marking this answered, just in case any more discussion goes on. So I'll check back. Thanks again.