# F# constant pattern matching and checks elimination

Tags: f#, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I`m pretty new to F# world and currently trying to experiment with functions. Trying to find new techniques to make them more compact and flexible and move from C#-like coding style.
So I have a pretty ugly code of mine with constant checking and pattern matching:

```
type StringChecking =
    | Success of string
    | Fail

    let StringProcessor(str : string) =
        let newstr = modifyFn str
        let result = checkFn newstr
        match result with
        | true -> Success result
        | false ->
            let newstr' = modifyFn' str
            let result' = checkFn newstr'
            match result' with
            | true -> Success newstr'
            | false -> 
                let newstr'' = modifyFn'' str
                let result'' = checkFn newstr''
                match result'' with
                | true -> Success newstr''
                | false -> 
                    Fail
```

Are there some useful techniques that can help me to eliminate all these stages and make my code more elegant. Sorry if the question seems awkward or stupid, but I really want to do something with this one, because I want to use it in some project of mine. I`ve grown pretty tired of constant checks in C#. Thank you for your time and suggestions.

Comment: A good reading for this kind of problems is "Railway oriented programming" http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part1/ and http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2/

Comment: This question seems quite similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32922378/126014

Comment: @Functional_S Thank you for this link. That`s a really good article. My F# journey started from that website. This and suggestions about monadic approach below are probably what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

### The Successful Path

[image]

This is assuming the objective is transforming an object repeatedly in a chain of steps when only on successful completion of the previous the next step will be performed. This will be encapsulated by F#'s `Option` type here.

If you are after conciseness, you could do worse than with some kind of monadic [bind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29).

```
let (>>=) arg f =   // bind operator
    match arg with
    | Some x -> f x
    | None -> None

let checkWith checker x =
    if checker x then Some x else None
"sample String"
|> (modifyFn >> checkWith checkFn)
>>= (modifyFn' >> checkWith checkFn')
>>= (modifyFn'' >> checkWith checkFn'')
```

But you do notice the awkward first step in the pipelining. which results from the unwrapped value at the beginning of the computation. Thus:

```
Success "sample String"
>>= (modifyFn >> checkWith checkFn)
>>= (modifyFn' >> checkWith checkFn')
>>= (modifyFn'' >> checkWith checkFn'')
```

In case you wanted to modify and validate the same original value instead of the result of the previous step, let's simply ignore it.

```
let str ="sample String"
modifyFn str |> checkWith checkFn
>>= (fun _ -> modifyFn' str |> checkWith checkFn')
>>= (fun _ -> modifyFn'' str |> checkWith checkFn'')
```

### The Alternative Path

[image]

In the case that the computation terminates with the successful completion of a step, otherwise to continue with alternative steps, we will have different signatures. Akin to F#'s `defaultArg` function (`arg:'T option -> defaultvalue:'T > 'T`), I'll propose a bind-like `defaultBy`:

```
let defaultBy c a f =
    match a with
    | None -> f c
    | x -> x
let (>?=) f = defaultBy "sample string" f

"sample string"
|> (modifyFn >> checkWith checkFn)
>?= (modifyFn' >> checkWith checkFn')
>?= (modifyFn'' >> checkWith checkFn'')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Yeah, 3rd case is more suitable for me. I've read about monads and wanted to try them. So am I right to assume that in the 3rd example, in case of Fail result in whatever step of validation it will continue to modify and validate original string until Success result/until the end of this whole expression? Because I`m currently debugging in order to understand how this structure is working.

Comment: It seems that in this case if teh first part of expression returns Fail everything below won`t be evaluated and the whole comp. expression returns Fail. So in my case  StringChecking type needs to be modified.

Answer (score 4):

Monads are perfect for this!

If instead of defining your own type you use F#'s option, there's already a function exactly for this as `Option.bind`. For reference, here's the implementation:

```
module Option =
    let bind m f =
        match m with
        | Some(x) -> f x
        | None -> None
```

You can use it like so:

```
let stringProcessor str =
    str
    |> (modifyFn >> checkFn)
    |> Option.bind (modifyFn' >> checkFn)
    |> Option.bind (modifyFn'' >> checkFn'')
```

This is nice, but believe it or not, there's a way to actually get rid of the little remaining repetitiveness using computational expressions (also known as do-notation in Haskell). First, let's look at the final code real quick:

```
type OptionBuilder() =
    member this.Bind (x, f) = Option.bind f x
    member this.Return x = Some(x)
    member this.ReturnFrom x = x

let option = new OptionBuilder()

let stringProcessor x =
    option {
        let! x' = x |> modifyFn |> checkFn
        let! x'' = x' |> modifyFn' |> checkFn'
        return! x'' |> modifyFn'' |> checkFn'' }
```

To understand this, let's start from a different angle. Consider that in functional languages, name binding is actually just function application in disguise. Don't believe me? Well, this snippet:

```
let x = f a b
doSomething x
doSomethingElse (x + 1)
```

can be thought of syntactic sugar for:

```
(fun x ->
    doSomething x
    doSomethingElse (x + 1))
(f a b)
```

And this:

```
let a = 1
let b = 2
a * b
```

is interchangeable with this:

```
(fun a ->
    (fun b ->
        a * b)
     2)
 1
```

Or, more generally, `let var = value in expr` (where `expr` is all the code that comes after the simple kind of let binding) is interchangeable with `(fun var -> expr) value`.

This is how a computation expression's `let!` and `Bind` are related. We can take that let binding rule we just saw and examine how it works with computation expressions. This form:

```
comp { let! var = value in expr }
```

is equivalent to

```
comp.Bind (value, (fun var -> comp { expr }))
```

where we apply the same rule to `expr`. Additionally, there are many other forms defined, such as `return`, which you can find here [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233182.aspx). Now, as an example, let's try to desugar this:

```
comp {
    let! x' = f x
    let! x'' = f (x' + 1)
    return (g x) }
```

For our first step, pick off the first `let!` and desugar it. That give us:

```
comp.Bind (f x, (fun x' ->
    comp {
        let! x'' = f (x' + 1)
        return (g x) }
```

Doing this again gets us to:

```
comp.Bind (f x, fun x' ->
    comp.Bind (f x', (fun x'' ->
        comp { return (g x'') }))
```

Which will finally become:

```
comp.Bind (f x, fun x' ->
    comp.Bind (f x', (fun x'' ->
        comp.Return (g x''))
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for your answer. I will try this as well. Computation expressions are interesting, but a bit tricky for me to understand. But i`ll continue to try!

Comment: I don`t know why but i`m getting "this expression was expecting to have type 'a option but here has type 'b * 'c" compiler error. My checkFn functions must return option in this case as far as i can understand, but still..

Comment: @ZInodust ah, that's my fault for not checking what I wrote. It was a mistake in the definition the builder's Bind method, but it's fixed now.